# Convert timestamp to datetime for a Vaex dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, parquet, vaex

I have a parquet file that I have loaded as a Vaex dataframe. The parquette file has a column for a timestamp in the format 2022-10-12 17:10:00+00:00.

When I try to do any kind of analysis with my dataframe I get the following error.

```
KeyError: "Unknown variables or column: 'isna(timestamp)'"
```

When I remove that column everything works. I assume that the time column is not in the correct format. But I have been having trouble converting it.

I tryed
`df['timestamp']= pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].astype(str))` but I get the error `<class 'vaex.expression.Expression'> is not convertible to datetime` I assume I can't mix pandas and vaex.

I am also having trouble producing a  minimal reproducible example since when I create a dataframe, the datatime column would be a string and everthing works fine.

Comment: How exactly do you load the parquet file into vaex? What's the type of the timestamp column in the parquet file?

Comment: I've imported the file using, df= vx.open('FILE'). The timestamp is timestamp[us, tz=UTC].